# Copy Product from website to website programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, product, programmatically, multi-website

In the admin you can do this:

[image]

which is pretty easy to copy a product from one website to another, with the values of another website.

Is there a way to do this programmatically?

EDIT:

I've tried this:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$websiteIds = $product->getWebsiteIds(); //fetch product current websiteIds 
array_push($websiteIds, 5);
$product->setWebsiteIds($websiteIds); //assigning website IDs
$product->save();
```

And yes, add the product to the other website but with the Default Values. And I don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

i think i have an idea let me share with you, look coping a product is nothing but duplicating the existing product with different sku and website id.

when you are writing a program for this load product by sku or id and while insereting change sku of that product as well as website id.

Comment: But what I want is the same product (same sku) but adding it to a website with the same values of the Main Store (for example).